# Function to calculate the percentage each value has in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am taking part in the Titanic Tutorials over at Kaggle to learn pandas/machine learning.

Here is my kernel: https://www.kaggle.com/trenzalore888/titanic/titanic-learning

I want to create a function which takes two arguments, dataframe and column name. I want this function to calculate the percentage each class is (assuming it's binary, i.e. 0 or 1).

I can do this hard coded i.e. to work specifically for the Titanic set, but I want to create a function so I can use it in the future.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
traintotal=(len(train.index))
testtotal=(len(test.index))

def Is_data_imbalanced (df,objectivecolumn) :
    objectivecount= df.objectivecolumn[df.objectivecolumn > 0].sum()
    objectivecountpercentage=(objectivecount/traintotal)*100
    objectivecountrounded= np.ceil(objectivecountpercentage)
    return objectivecountrounded

Is_data_imbalanced(train,"Survived")
```

Unfortunately I get an attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'objectivecolumn'

Below is the hardcoded version that works:

```
traintotal=(len(train.index))
print("there are", traintotal,"rows in the train data")

testtotal=(len(test.index))
print("there are {} rows in the test data".format(testtotal))

Survialcount= train.Survived[train.Survived > 0].sum()
Survialcountpercentage=(Survialcount/traintotal)*100
print(Survialcountpercentage)

survivalcountrounded= np.ceil(Survialcountpercentage)

print(" ",survivalcountrounded,"percent survived")
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work? It seems like it takes `df` for train fine, but the 2nd argument `columnname` for `.Survived` is not working.

Comment: Try `objectivecount= df[objectivecolumn][df[objectivecolumn] > 0]].sum()`, It needs to be explicitly typed to access with "." notation. Attribute access is generally flimsy, try to use .loc or [].

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works great now. Will try to get into the habit of using [ ] instead of .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it really is binary then all you need is

```
def Is_data_imbalanced(df, objectivecolumn):
    return int(df[objectivecolumn].mean() * 100)
```